# Using file located on a remote http server in pig LOAD statement?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to read a txt file in a pig job and join it with data located on our hdfs.

So basically what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
current_ids = LOAD 'http://host/dir/file.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int);
bindings = LOAD '$hdfs_path' USING AvroStorage();
joined_ids = JOIN current_ids BY id, bindings by user_id;
```

First: Is this possible? I assume it is.

Second: How do I do this, or where can I look to get some more answers. I've been surprisingly stuck on this issue :).

We'd prefer to not have to upload the txt file to our hdfs, if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asked this questions to some hadoop experts and they replied:

"You can't do that. Download it manually and CopyFromLocal to put in HDFS.. Otherwise we'd be likely to DDoS a poor little webserver with our Hadoop cluster"

Problem solved!